# Ruby on Rails: undefined method, checking boolean if true statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, syntax-error

I have a page where I'm checking to see if the database column `public` is true or if a user is admin.

```
<% if @user.public || current_user.admin %>
  ... users page ...
<% end %>
```

The issue right now is that if I'm not logged in, then its checking if `current_user.admin` is true, so I get a **NoMethodError**

> undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass

What is the most logical syntax so I can check if its public or admin if I'm not logged in, so it should direct to a noticed page instead of getting this error.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have an `@user` variable and `current_user` variable? That seems redundant...

Comment: @GavinMiller because a user can be `current_user` which is logged in, or `@user` which is users that are not logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if `current user` is *set* before checking whether it's an `admin`:

```
if @user.public || (current_user && current_user.admin)
```

#### Updated answer

[Ruby 2.3.0 introduced the Safe Navigation operator (`&.`).](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/)

This makes the code even nicer:

```
if @user.public || current_user&.admin
```

Comment: Assuming that `current_user` is coming from an authentication gem, adding `current_user = <code_to_find_user> || User.new` eliminates the need for extra conditionals.

Comment: `current_user&.admin`

Comment: @maguri: Ruby 2.3 wasn't released at the time this question was asked but have updated the answer for newcomers :-)